# How to create a cumulative variable that groups by PERMNO and arranges by date in R

Tags: r, wrds, wrds-compusat

I have a dataframe with variables from COMPUSTAT containing data on various accounting items, including SG&A expenses from different companies.

I want to create a new variable in the dataframe which accumulates the SG&A expenses for each company in chronological order. I use PERMNO codes as the unique ID for each company.

I have tried this code, however it does not seem to work:

```
crsp.comp2$cxsgaq <- crsp.comp2 %>%
  group_by(permno) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(xsgaq), cumsum(xsgaq))
```

(xsgag is the COMPUSTAT variable for SG&A expenses)

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: why not this? `crsp.comp2 %>%
  group_by(permno) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(xsgaq = cumsum(xsgaq))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example code is attempting write the entire dataframe `crsp.comp2`, into a variable `crsp.comp2$cxsgaq`.

Usually the `vars()` function variables needs to be "quoted"; though in your situation, use the standard `mutate()` function and assign the `cxsgaq` variable there.

```
crsp.comp2 <- crsp.comp2 %>%
  group_by(permno) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(cxsgaq = cumsum(xsgaq))
```

Reproducible example with iris dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  arrange(Sepal.Length) %>% 
  mutate(C.Sepal.Width = cumsum(Sepal.Width))
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer from @m-viking, if using the WRDS PostgreSQL server, you would simply use `window_order` (from `dplyr`) in place of `arrange`. (I use the Compustat firm identifier `gvkey` in place of `permno` so that this code works, but the idea is the same.)

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DBI)

pg <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), 
                bigint = "integer", sslmode='allow')

fundq <- tbl(pg, sql("SELECT * FROM comp.fundq"))

comp2 <-
  fundq %>%
  filter(indfmt == "INDL", datafmt == "STD",
         consol == "C", popsrc == "D")

comp2 <- 
  comp2 %>%
  group_by(gvkey) %>%
  dbplyr::window_order(datadate) %>%
  mutate(cxsgaq = cumsum(xsgaq))

comp2 %>%
  filter(!is.na(xsgaq)) %>%
  select(gvkey, datadate, xsgaq, cxsgaq)
#> # Source:     lazy query [?? x 4]
#> # Database:   postgres [iangow@wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu:9737/wrds]
#> # Groups:     gvkey
#> # Ordered by: datadate
#>    gvkey  datadate   xsgaq cxsgaq
#>    <chr>  <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 001000 1966-12-31 0.679  0.679
#>  2 001000 1967-12-31 1.02   1.70 
#>  3 001000 1968-12-31 5.86   7.55 
#>  4 001000 1969-12-31 7.18  14.7  
#>  5 001000 1970-12-31 8.25  23.0  
#>  6 001000 1971-12-31 7.96  30.9  
#>  7 001000 1972-12-31 7.55  38.5  
#>  8 001000 1973-12-31 8.53  47.0  
#>  9 001000 1974-12-31 8.86  55.9  
#> 10 001000 1975-12-31 9.59  65.5  
#> # … with more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>